# Broadleaf commerce where does Shipping Information be populated

Tags: e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I have been playing around Broadleaf commerce for a few days and found that it is a great framework. Thanks for all of those who built this. However, I am facing a problem and am waiting anyone to help. The problem I found can be reproduced by following below steps:

- Go to "Manage Addresses" page of the user.
- Delete an address.
- Go to "Check out" page and you will see that such shipping information is still available inside the boxes.

Therefore, my question is I would like to know how such shipping information be populated. I also checked the table "blc_customer_address" and found that a row that represented such information was deleted, but the **blc_address.is_active** is still equal to **1**, which does not make sense.

By the way, I set up the website according to Broadleaf2.2, MySql database, and Apache Tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Broadleaf, we think about shipping information as 'Fulfillment Groups'. An Order can have multiple of these. For instance, if you have 2 items that you have added to an Order, you can send those to 2 different addresses. This would look something like:

```
Order 
    -> FulfillmentGroup
        -> FulfillmentGroupItem
            -> Product A
        -> Address 1 (ship to Chicago, Illinois)
    -> FulfillmentGroup
        -> FulfillmentGroupItem
            -> Product B
        -> Address 2 (ship to Dallas, Texas)
```

For Customers, you are right there is simply a relationship table called 'CustomerAddress' that just relates a Customer to an Address. However, when you delete something, this does not remove the address itself (because as you can see, that can also be related to a Fulfillment Group) and so it just deletes the relationship.